# Python 3.4 - Installing SciPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I'm having problem with installing package SciPy for python 3.4 on Windows 10.
There is an error I've got from cmd on admin mode. Other packages I installed correctly, such as numpy, scikit_learn, matplotlib.

[link to the cmd output](http://pastebin.com/T9tYBMMH)

Comment: @randomusername: yes, [screenshot](http://imagizer.imageshack.com/img540/7042/twZWup.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can download binary packages for Python on Windows here:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy

Comment: I tried to install package from here, but it shows the same error
typed python -m pip install "file_location\scipy.whl"